# How can I install osd-lyrics on Kubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, kubuntu

https://github.com/osdlyrics/osdlyrics

I want to install this app to my kubuntu. I downloaded it via clone button but when I click to .sh files, it doesnt install, it opens text editor to show code.

Step by step please.

Answer (score 1):

From the README file:

> OSD Lyrics is available for Ubuntu in our [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~osd-lyrics/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and for ArchLinux
>   through community repo and through AUR.

Add the PPA  `ppa:osd-lyrics/ppa` from osd-lyrics' Launchpad PPA to your Software Sources via `apt`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:osd-lyrics/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

then proceed with the installation by

```
sudo apt-get install osdlyrics
```

It is recommended you take a read at [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)